# how to stop() the last loop among multiple nested asyncio loops?

Tags: python, loops, python-asyncio, halt

I need at times more than one asyncio coroutine, where the routines then would be nested : coroutine B running in coroutine A, C in B and so on.  The problem is with stopping a given loop.  For example, using loop.stop() in the last top loop such as loop 'C' kills actually all asyncio coroutines - and not just this loop 'C'.  I suspect that stop() actually kills coroutine A, and by doing so it annihilates all other dependent routines.  The nested routines are call_soon_threadsafe, and all routines begin as run_forever.

I tried using specific loop names, or 'return', or 'break' (in the while loop inside the coroutine) but nothing exits the loop - except stop() which then kills non-specifically all loops at once.

My problem I described here is actually related to an earlier question of mine...
[python daemon server crashes during HTML popup overlay callback using asyncio websocket coroutines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30688835/python-daemon-server-crashes-during-html-popup-overlay-callback-using-asyncio-we)
...which I thought I had solved - till running into this loop.stop() problem.

below now my example code for Python 3.4.3 where I try to stop() the coroutine_overlay_websocket_server loop as soon as it is done with the websocket job. As said, my code at the current state breaks all running loops. Thereafter the fmDaemon recreates a new asyncio loop that knows nothing of what was computed before :

```
import webbrowser
import websockets
import asyncio

class fmDaemon( Daemon):

    # Daemon - see : http://www.jejik.com/articles/2007/02/a_simple_unix_linux_daemon_in_python/
    # Daemon - see : http://www.jejik.com/files/examples/daemon3x.py

    def __init__( self, me):
        self.me = me

    def run( self):

        while True:

            @asyncio.coroutine
            def coroutine_daemon_websocket_server( websocket, path):

                msg = yield from websocket.recv()

                if msg != None:
                    msg_out = "{}".format( msg)
                    yield from websocket.send( msg_out)
                    self.me = Function1( self.me, msg)

            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
            loop.run_until_complete( websockets.serve( coroutine_daemon_websocket_server, self.me.IP, self.me.PORT))
            loop.run_forever()


def Function1( me, msg):

    # doing some stuff :
    # creating HTML file,
    # loading HTML webpage with a webbrowser call,
    # awaiting HTML button press signal via websocket protocol :

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def coroutine_overlay_websocket_server( websocket, path):

        while True:
            msg = yield from websocket.recv()
            msg_out = "{}".format( msg)
            yield from websocket.send( msg_out)

            if msg == 'my_expected_string':
                me.flags['myStr'] = msg
                break

        loop.call_soon_threadsafe( loop.stop)

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.call_soon_threadsafe( asyncio.async, websockets.serve( coroutine_overlay_websocket_server, me.IP, me.PORT_overlay))
    loop.run_forever()
    loop.call_soon_threadsafe( loop.close)

    # program should continue here...
```

My two questions : 1) Is there a way to exit a given coroutine without killing a coroutine lower down?  2) Or, alternatively, do you know of a method for reading websocket calls that does not make use of asyncio ?

Comment: Can you include some example code that demonstrates what you're describing? Typically no matter how many coroutines you have, you've only got one event loop, so calling `loop.stop()` is going to shut down everything. It sounds like you may be misusing the framework if you're starting a different loop for every coroutine.

Comment: Usually you don't need multiple loops in the same thread. Just call `loop.run_forever()` and let him do all work. 
Why do you need multiple `run_until_complete` on the same loop (`get_event_loop()` returns existing one, don't creates new)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm still a little confused by what you're trying to do, but there's definitely no need to try to nest event loops - your program is single-threaded, so when you call `asyncio.get_event_loop()` multiple times, you're always going to get the same event loop back. So you're really not creating two different loops in your example; both `fmDaemon.run` and `Function1` use the same one. That's why stopping `loop` inside `Function1` also kills the coroutine you launched inside `run`.

That said, there's no reason to try to create two different event loops to begin with. `Function1` is being called from a coroutine, and wants to call other coroutines, so why not make it a coroutine, too? Then you can just call `yield from websockets.serve(...)` directly, and use an `asyncio.Event` to wait for `coroutine_overlay_websocket_server` to complete:

```
import webbrowser
import websockets
import asyncio

class fmDaemon( Daemon):
    def __init__( self, me):
        self.me = me

    def run( self):
        @asyncio.coroutine
        def coroutine_daemon_websocket_server(websocket, path):
            msg = yield from websocket.recv()

            if msg != None:
                msg_out = "{}".format( msg)
                yield from websocket.send( msg_out)
                self.me = Function1( self.me, msg)

        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.run_until_complete(websockets.serve(coroutine_daemon_websocket_server, 
                                                 self.me.IP, 
                                                 self.me.PORT))
        loop.run_forever()


@asyncio.coroutine
def Function1(me, msg):
    @asyncio.coroutine
    def coroutine_overlay_websocket_server(websocket, path):

        while True:
            msg = yield from websocket.recv()
            msg_out = "{}".format( msg)
            yield from websocket.send( msg_out)

            if msg == 'my_expected_string':
                me.flags['myStr'] = msg
                break

        event.set() # Tell the outer function it can exit.

    event = asyncio.Event()
    yield from websockets.serve(coroutine_overlay_websocket_server, me.IP, me.PORT_overlay))
    yield from event.wait() # This will block until event.set() is called.
```

Comment: Here - a little bit late - some feedback, and many thanks to Dano, László Márai at CodeMentor and others.  The solution was to use in each link a "yield from function1", "yield from function2" and so on whenever an asyncio.coroutine call exists in the very last functionN at the end of a chain of function calls.  That's it : The cascade of function calls unfolds flawlessly.